# execve function always failed in c++

Tags: c++, linux, fork, system-calls, execve

I have a program that forks two children.

The first child lists the home directory content and saves it in a text file and makes two directories, one for saving c++ file and one for saving the text files.

The second child uses the `execve` function to execute another program called `arrange_files`. That program reads the text file resulted from `ls` command and moves the cpp files to cfiles directory and the text files to txtfiles directory

I am new to c++ and the  problem is the  `execve` system call that always returns -1

This is parent.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include<sys/wait.h>
 #include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
  pid_t  child1,child2; 
  child1 = fork();
   
  if(child1==0){
  //child 1 code 
    
  system("ls >> Myfiles.txt");
  system("mkdir Cfiles");
  system("mkdir txtfiles");
    
  }
  else if(child1>0) 
  { 
  // this is parent

 
 
  child2 =fork(); 
  wait(NULL);

  if(child2==0){
    //child 2 code 
  char * args[2]; 
  string st = "./arrange_files"; 
  args[0]= (char *) st.c_str(); 
  args[1]= NULL;
   
  if(execve("./arrange_files", args ,NULL)==-1)
    cout<<"Somthing went wrong!"<<endl;
    
    
  }
  
  }// end of else
  

return 0;
}
```

and  this is arrange_files.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>   // include the fstream (file stream library)
#include<string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
 
// declaring an input file called infile 
ifstream infile;   

// opening the input file (file we will read from) that called myfiles.txt  
 infile.open("Myfiles.txt");   
    
string line;

// loop to read the content of the file line by line till the end of the file
while(getline(infile,line))  
{

if(line.find("txt") != string::npos){
string command= "mv " +line + " txtfiles";
system(command.c_str());
}
else if(line.find("cpp")!= string::npos){
string command= "mv " +line + " Cfiles";
system(command.c_str());


}
infile.close(); 

}//end of while loop
return 0;. 
}// end of the program
```

Comment: Is the executable in your working directory?

Comment: I recommend reading documentation about `errno`

Comment: yes it is on my working directory @molbdnilo

Comment: As eerorika said, you should look at the errno. If it's a filesystem error, I would try adding the absolute path to the binary instead to test it. Since execve and PATH don't play nice, it wouldn't surprise me if the working directory didn't either.

Comment: Furthermore, execve doesn't just execute a program, it totally replaces yours with it. As a result, no code after the execve will execute if it's successful. You probably don't want that if you just want to run a program.

Comment: I put the errno variable and it shows 2 even I pass full path